# While loop that break when the sum of the values in column reach certain value

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a while loop, which breaks when the sum of the values in a column reach certain value. This is my code:

```
while sum(new_mass_not_in_whitelist1.records_to_select) == 7600:
    new_mass_not_in_whitelist1['records_to_select'] = [math.ceil(int((el * difference_new_old_mass) / freq_sum))
                                              for el in new_mass_not_in_whitelist1['freq']]
```

Before entering the while loop `new_mass_not_in_whitelist1['records_to_select']` is filled with NaN.

Comment: so you are using dataframe?

Comment: If your `sum` is growing and you want to stop at `7600` use `while my_sum != 7600` or `while my_sum < 7600`

Answer (score 1):

I think you did a mistake here.

```
while sum(new_mass_not_in_whitelist1.records_to_select) == 7600:
```

You should use `!=` to break loop when sum is equal to `7600`

Like this

```
while sum(new_mass_not_in_whitelist1.records_to_select) != 7600:
```

OR:

If the sum is growing you can also use less than operator `<`

Like this

```
while sum(new_mass_not_in_whitelist1.records_to_select) < 7600:
```